# Writing out a file via SSH, sometimes RSA key is accepted, sometimes not

Tags: python, c, ssh, rsa, scp

**Background**

I'm using scp to transfer files from my host machine (Ubuntu 15) to another machine in my network (also Ubuntu 15). I've gone through the key exchange process already. The primary program is written in C, which calls a Python script containing the shell command for scp and some logic for errorhandling and file creation.

**Problem**
When I run the C program, which creates the output that I'm interested in moving, the SSH connection to the remote host will sometimes accept my RSA key and sometimes not, during the same session. The C code looks like this:

```
if (-1 == system(sndCtl.txVoiceMessageCommand)) {
            E_FATAL("Command Line invocation of txMessage.py failed");
```

The output of sndCtl.txMessageCommand is something of the form:

```
khtad>python3 txMessage.py localfilepath useraccout@remotehost:remotefilepath
```

which works just fine--it sends the local file to the remote location, we're all good. However, when I run the code a few times in a row during the same session, sometimes the file will transfer without a password prompt (as it should, the machines have swapped RSA keys and have write-permission to each other), but sometimes it will ask for a password. When prompted for a password, if the password is entered on the command line, the file transfer takes place as intended. If not, the file transfer fails.

The baffling thing is that sometimes it works. If it always failed, I think I could have found the error by this point. Could this be a timing issue? Should I include a sleep() in my python code to make sure the scp has time to exchange keys? Is it something else altogether that I'm missing?

**Edit update:** The key exchange with the remotehost also fails after I renew its DHCP lease, whether or not the address is the same. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: What is your SSH server?

Comment: By that do you mean which implementation of SSH? OpenSSH is what I'm using.

Comment: Or if you mean SSH v1 or v2, I'm using v2.

Comment: I was asking because there's a known problem with ProFTPD server that manifests similarly to your problem.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to that behavior explanation? I'd like to read up on it for future reference.

Comment: http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3992